# Using th:object without Model

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to make form with `th:object` for every element of array.But I got error. The problem is `th:object` is used only for object which was saved on Model. How can use `th:object` and `th:field` on `th:each`, or any other ideas to solve it?

```
<tr th:each="sect: ${process.sectionData}" th:if="${sect.sectionType==1}">
       <form th:action="@{'/process/section/save/' + ${sect.id} }" method="post" th:object="${sect}">
          <td>
             <button>
                save
             </button>
          </td>
          <td>
             <input
                 type="text"
                 th:field="*{sect.name}"
                 class="m-inline"
                 placeholder="Страна проведения"/>
          </td>
        </form>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

`th:field` is just a shortcut that sets the `name`, `id`, and `value` of an input field.  You should be able to do this and have it work:

```
<tr th:each="sect: ${process.sectionData}" th:if="${sect.sectionType==1}">
  <form th:action="@{'/process/section/save/' + ${sect.id}}" method="post">
    <td>
       <button>save</button>
    </td>
    
    <td>
       <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          th:value="${sect.name}"
          class="m-inline"
          placeholder="Страна проведения" />
    </td>
  </form>
</tr>
```